# Where do I get Glass Bottles?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I have 200k, upgraded my house and have Iroha at a Red Heart having seen all her heart events. My last requirement to marry her would be the bed which requires fabric.

I assume that for me to get fabric I need the right Maker to make my wool into the fabric I need. However every maker requires Glass Bottles.  Where do I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out, there are 2 ways of getting them

1. Fishing, this is done either with the rod or the traps, i could recommend the traps as you can get multiple bottles this way and their easier to get stuff from than the rod not just because of how the rod works but the traps can get set in 3 places at the same time
2. Trade, you need to arrange with someone on the internet prior because of how the trading works as you select an item before you enter (didn't realize this and traded a pink diamond for an egg, still, i had 5 more so it was no big lose)